# Rotate player to face direction it's moving in 3D space

Tags: c#, xna-4.0, models

I'm making a 3D game in XNA4.0. How do I rotate a model to face the direction that the user is pressing. I assume I need to set its look at to the direction being pressed, but can't figure out how to do that.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the world matrix with Matrix.CreateWorld(Position, Direction, Up);

Direction is the forward vector of your model...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb975261.aspx